# Why can't I override this method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm trying to override a python class (first time doing this), and I can't seem to override this method.  When I run this, my recv method doesn't run.  It runs the superclasses's method instead.  What am I doing wrong here?  (This is python 2.7 by the way.)

```
import socket

class PersistentSocket(socket.socket):
    def recv(self, count):
        print("test")
        return super(self.__class__, self).recv(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = PersistentSocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 2300))
    print(s.recv(1)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say it runs the superclasses's method instead, you mean it doesn't print "test"?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I even commented out the return line, but it still reads a character, so it's definitely not running my recv function.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the socket.recv definition was different than mine (allowed for flags), so I changed my function definition to recv(self, bufsize, flags = None), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `super(self.__class__, self)` - **never do that**. If it was that easy, 0-argument `super` would have existed on Python 2. `self.__class__` is the wrong class for subclass instances.

Comment: Should it be `super(PersistentSocket, self).recv(bufsize, flags)` instead?

Comment: @Dave: It should. That won't fix the problem you're currently facing, and due to the weird design decisions of whoever wrote the `socket` module, I don't think there's a good way to fix this problem, but you should stop passing `self.__class__` to `super` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The socket type (officially `socket.SocketType`, though `socket.socket` happens to be the same object) makes the strange choice of implementing `recv` and a few other methods as instance attributes, rather than as normal methods in the class dict. In `socket.SocketType.__init__`, it sets a `self.recv` instance attribute that overrides the `recv` method you tried to define.

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do you know something like that?  I couldn't find it documented.  Is this just from the library source code?

Comment: @Dave: I read the source, which you can find [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/socket.py#l179). You'll also see a few other weird interactions due to the use of `__slots__`.

Answer (score 0):

Picking on the explanation from @user2357112, one thing that seems to have helped is to do a `delattr(self, 'recv')` on the class constructor (inheriting from `socket.SocketType`) and then define you own `recv` method; for example:

```
class PersistentSocket(socket.SocketType):
    def __init__(self):
        """As usual."""
        delattr(self, 'recv')
    def recv(self, buffersize=1024, flags=0):
        """Your own implementation here."""
        return None
```